# GIF image keeps looping even with repeat=False parameter in FuncAnimation using Pillow writer

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif, matplotlib-animation

I've added a dummy "init" function since I've read somewhere that it might be the cause but it didn't helped and I still can't figure out why it is constantly looping.
Also "repeat_delay" parameter is not working as well and there are no any errors thrown in console.

Example of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(-20, 20)
ax.set_xlim(-20, 20)

circle_size = 400

point_anim1 = ax.scatter(10, 10, s=circle_size, c='red')
point_anim2 = ax.scatter(-10, -4, s=circle_size, c='blue')

arrow = patches.Arrow(2, 2, 2, 2)
ax.add_patch(arrow)
frames = 4


def init():
    return arrow, point_anim1, point_anim2


def animate(i):
    global point_anim1, point_anim2
    point_anim1.remove()
    point_anim2.remove()
    if i % 2:
        point_anim1 = ax.scatter(10, 10, s=circle_size * i, c='red')
        point_anim2 = ax.scatter(-10, -4, s=circle_size * i, c='blue')
        arrow.set_visible(False)
    else:
        point_anim1 = ax.scatter(10, 10, s=circle_size, c='red')
        point_anim2 = ax.scatter(-10, -4, s=circle_size, c='blue')
        arrow.set_visible(True)
    return arrow, point_anim1, point_anim2


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=frames, interval=600, repeat=False#, repeat_delay=5000
)
plt.show()
plt.close()

anim.save('test.gif', writer='pillow')
```